# summary of categorical variables from multiple imputed data in sas

Tags: statistics, sas, analysis

I am using SAS for multiple imputation. After imputing data and using proc freq I want to have frequency tables of the imputed data. I am not able to produce frequency tables. Below is the code I have tried. Any help will be appreciated. I guess I am doing some mistake in second and third steps (codes).

```
proc    mi     data=data1 nimpute=5 seed=54321 out=imput
min= 27 1 1 17.6354
max= 77 6 3 46.6550;
class age work;
fcs discrim (work edu/details) reg(age bmi);
var age work edu bmi;
run;

proc freq data=aa.osa_revised1;
tables work*edu/chisq;
run;

proc freq data=imput;
tables _imputation_*work*edu/chisq;
ods output chisq=out;
run;

proc mianalyze parms=out ;
modeleffects frequency percentage ;
run ;
```

Comment: Proc freq should work. Are there any errors or what happens?

Comment: Can you give more detail as to what you aren't able to produce from the frequency table? "Not able to produce a table" in SAS can mean a lot of things ;)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I get frequency table for all replicates seperately. I'm unable to get the combined frequency and chisq statistics using the last two codes.